# What is needed to run ELF binaries compiled from android APKs? (understanding android internals)

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, elf

I'm trying to understand how Android works internally. Before ART, it used Dalvik to run java code. I guess it created a Dalkiv process in 'Linux' kernel which was simply a VM that ran the dex bytecode.

For ART, the dex bytecode is compiled into instructions in the processor's architecture (happens during the installation process). This compiled dex bytecode is stored into an ELF binary. So it's somethig that 'Linux' kernel can understand.

So suppose I wanted to run this ELF binary on Linux. Besides `ashmem` and `binder` kernel modules, what more would I need? Which libraries do this ELF binary require? Is this ELF binary simply launched as a linux process?

I tried reading anbox.io source code, but I couldn't understand how it launched an ELF binary from an APK. Maybe understanding what it's required to run it will make me understand anbox.io's source code better.

I also found https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/refs/heads/master/runtime/ but I don't know where to begin. What is /runtime? Is it a program, a library? Is Android Runtime something that is linked together with the ELF binary generated from dex bytecode?

Comment: "For questions other than development or programming, but related to the Android framework, use this link: https://android.stackexchange.com."

Comment: i don't think this is the correct place for your question, you'd have more luck asking on a different site :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody before asking I went in the page that displays all the stackexchange sites and couldn't find any. I think android.stackexchange.com is for things related to framework and not android internals :(

Comment: yeah it's tricky, i'm sure someone with more experience will be able to help you out, either by moving your question or by answering it :)